# Learn Python 2 or 3?

Tags: python

I already bought a good book on Python 2.5. Should I return it and get a book on 3.1 instead? that I know this question has already been asked, but I wanted a more up-to-date answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Linky: [Python2orPython3](http://wiki.python.org/moin/Python2orPython3)

Synopsis:
Python 2.5 is old but the general consensus is Python 3 if you don't have any dependencies or a large code base already in production, if this is the case then writing more future ready code might be a better option. On the other hand bigger projects have already started the long process of porting their code.

When you learn python really you should learn 2 and 3 and then just remember the differences between them. Its not like a different language all together and you could probably get most of the differences on a cheat sheet.

Answer (score 1):

You probably should learn Python 3, unless you're planning to work on a significant 2.x codebase anytime soon.

2.x and 3.x aren't actually all that different.  It's quite possible to use a common subset for most things.  EG, I just wrote a 4000 line deduplicating backup system that runs on 2.x and 3.x.

Answer (score 1):

They are similar enough that it makes sense to learn either 2.7 or 3.2, then learn the differences if they are important to you.

There's a guide on the Python site: http://wiki.python.org/moin/Python2orPython3

Answer (score 1):

For the time being 2.x and 3.x will live side by side. So you should learn "both". BUT actualy they are so similar, that you will learn the differences as you tag along. Keep your book, you won't learn something wrong, which you would have to relearn later.

Actualy it may be better, NOT to start with 3.x, becuase you may come along some legacy code which you might have problems understanding, because they use "deprecated" constructs to accomplish something.

On the other hand if you come accross some new constructs, you will begin to compare it, with how you would do it in python 2.x and you might find it easier to remember how something is done generaly in python, because you gain experience and understanding through overthinking the underlying concepts and reasonings why something changed.